# plot circle with gradient gray scale color in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to draw a circle with gradient color in matlab, but I can't. Is there any one that can help me?

[the sample image can be found here](http://www.webdesign.org/img_articles/15032/013.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one approach -

```
N = 200; %// this decides the size of image
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-1:1/N:1, -1:1/N:1) ;
nrm = sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2);
out = uint8(255*(nrm/min(nrm(:,1)))); %// output image

figure, imshow(out) %// show image
```

Output -

[image]

---

If you would like to pad the output with white boundary as shown in the expect output image, you can do so with **[`padarray`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/padarray.html)** -

```
padsize = 50; %// decides the boundary width
out = padarray(out,[padsize padsize],255);
```