# Creating a circle with a gradient

Tags: matlab

In a different thread, I found this bit of code to make a circle that has a gradient in it ([plot circle with gradient gray scale color in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26796113/plot-circle-with-gradient-gray-scale-color-in-matlab)):

```
N = 200; %// this decides the size of image
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-1:1/N:1, -1:1/N:1) ;
nrm = sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2);
out = uint8(255*(nrm/min(nrm(:,1)))); %// output image
padsize = 50; %// decides the boundary width
out = padarray(out,[padsize padsize],0);
figure, imshow(out) %// show image
```

Now I would like to replace that gradient with a fixed vector of decreasing values, so that every radius has it's own value.

Thanks in advance for any help on this

Comment: So what did *you* do yet? You're only posting someone else's work. Also, please ask a question, you did not do so. Questions in English are denoted by a question mark, ?, and can receive an answer. Please read [ask].

Comment: please provide a link to the other thread you mention.

Comment: Link added. Sorry, I'm new here and still learning....

Comment: Can you add your "vector of values" to your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an elegant way to replace elements with values from a vector:

Assume your vector is: `V = 283:-1:0`.
I used descending values for demonstration.
The value 283 is `sqrt(2)*N` (supposed to be the maximum radius in the bounding square).

Code differences from your original post:

1. Divide `out` by `max(out(:))` - set the range of out to `[0, 1]`.
2. Multiply by length of `V` (minus 1) - set the range of out to `[0, length(V)-1]`.
3. Use round instead of `uint8` (converting to `uint8` clamps value to `255`).
4. Use vector `V` as a Look Up Table - replace each elements of out with value of `V` in place of the value.

Here is the code:

```
N = 200; %// this decides the size of image

%V = round(sqrt(2)*N):-1:0;

%Assume this is your vector.
V = 283:-1:0;

[X,Y] = meshgrid(-1:1/N:1, -1:1/N:1) ;
nrm = sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2);
%out = uint8(255*(nrm/min(nrm(:,1)))); %// output image

%1. Divide by max(out(:)) - set the range of out to [0, 1].
%2. Multiply by length of V (minus 1) - set the range of out to [0, length(V)-1].
%3. Use round instead of uint8 (converting to uint8 clamps value to 255).
out = nrm/min(nrm(:,1));
out = round(out/max(out(:)) * (length(V)-1));

%4. Use vector V as a Look Up Table - replace each elements of out with value of V in place of the value.
out = V(out+1);

padsize = 50; %// decides the boundary width
out = padarray(out,[padsize padsize],0);
%figure, imshow(out) %// show image
figure, imagesc(out);impixelinfo;colormap hsv %// use imagesc for emphasis values.
```

As you can see, values are taken from vector `V`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
R = sqrt(X.^2+Y.^2);
out = uint8(255*R);
padsize = 50; %// decides the bounary width
out = padarray(out,[padsize padsize],0);
figure, imshow(out) %// show image
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I didn't describe the problem well.  I am trying to make the gradient according to a vector with length = radius of the circle. It sort of works with replacing all the values at a certain eccentricity form the center by the values in the vector. But it the code doesn't look very elegant...